# Why does chaining methods on a TempDir cause File creation to fail?

Tags: rust, tempdir

I'm a new rustecean, so I apologize if this question is silly.  I'm trying to understand why chaining methods on a `TempDir` causes `File::create` calls on the same `Path` to fail.

My situation is this: I'm writing a small library to convert between JSON and YAML to learn the language.  I'm trying to write a test which does the following:

1. Create a file with some json-encoded text
2. Deserialize it to ensure that it becomes a `serde_json::Value`

To do that, I've written the following code.

```
let temp_dir_path = TempDir::new("directory").expect("couldn't create directory");
let path = temp_dir.path().join("test-file.json");
let mut temp_file = File::create(&path).expect("failed to create file");
writeln!(temp_file, "{{\"key\": 2}}").expect("write failed");

// some stuff about loading the file and asserting on it
```

That works, but then I thought "why don't I just collapse the first two lines into one?"  So I tried that and wrote the following:

```
let path = TempDir::new("directory")
    .expect("couldn't create directory")
    .path()
    .join("test-file.json");
let mut temp_file = File::create(&path).expect("failed to create file");
writeln!(temp_file, "{{\"key\": 2}}").expect("write failed");
```

This code will consistently fail with a message of "failed to create file".  The thing I don't understand though is "why".  My intuition is that both of these calls should be the same (after all, I basically just inlined a variable); however, that clearly isn't happening.  Is there something I don't understand happening with `expect` here which causes it to not work in these situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean [`tempdir::TempDir`](https://docs.rs/tempdir/latest/tempdir/struct.TempDir.html) the docs state:

> Once the `TempDir` value is dropped, the directory at the path will be deleted,

which is exactly what happens to your [temporary value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html?highlight=temporary#temporaries) in the inlined variant at the end of the statement.